# time series clustering - how to limit the number of clusters (plot)

Tags: r, plot, time-series, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

When I run a plot on tsclust I see the Dendrogram attached. First, I would like to see only a certain number of clusters (e.g. 5). Right now I see every branch. Secondly, maybe you know better ways the present the results. I'm not really familiar with cluster analysis. Thanks!!

[image]

**Hierarchical cluster analysis (package: dtwclust)**

```
hc_sbd <- tsclust(stats.data2, type = "hierarchical", k = 10L,
              preproc = zscore, seed = 899,
              distance = "sbd", centroid = shape_extraction,
              control = hierarchical_control(method = "average"))

plot(hc_sbd)
```

Comment: Maybe `cutree` from base R will be helpful.

Comment: it works but how do I keep this in a dendrogram? because now I only have a cluster-vector

Comment: Looking at `?cutree` pointed me to `?dendrogram`. There is a function `cut.dendrogram` that may be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: A dendrogram like that must be interpreted as "no substantial clusters". There are some pairs, but no clear clusters. Don't force it. Accept that (e.g., due to parameters and preprocessing) there might be *no* clusters detectable.